# Problem with Github Actions IF expression syntax

Tags: if-statement, github-actions

I need to check if steps.get_acc.outputs.acc < 1 but right now the steps.get_acc.outputs.acc is a string how to make it an integer?

cml.yaml

```
name: MOPS
on: [push]
jobs:
  run:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: iterative/setup-cml@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'
      - name: cml
        id: get_acc
        shell: pwsh  
        env:
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          pip3 install -r requirements.txt
          python train.py
          $firstLine = Get-Content -Path 'metrics.txt' -TotalCount 1
          $digits = $firstline.Split(':')[-1]
          $acc = [int]$digits
          Write-Output "::set-output name=acc::$acc"        
    
      - name: Check acc
        if: ${{steps.get_acc.outputs.acc <1 }}
        uses: actions/github-script@v3
        with:
         script: |
          core.setFailed('Accuracy dropped')
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Github Documentation for output](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputs) explained that:

*The value that the output parameter will be mapped to can be set to a string or an expression with context. For example, you can use the steps context to set the value of an output to the output value of a step.*

Taking a look at the [Literals Github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#literals), we can note that:

*As part of an expression, we can use boolean, null, `number`, or string data types. Boolean literals are not case sensitive, so we can use true or True.*

[image]

Therefore, it all depends on the way you set the output variable.

**Example to set a number as output:**

```
outputs:
  random-number:
    description: "Random number"
    value: ${{ steps.random-number-generator.outputs.random-id }}
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - id: random-number-generator
      run: echo "::set-output name=random-id::$(echo $RANDOM)"
      shell: bash
```

**EDIT:**

Moreover the syntax you used for the `if` condition isn't correct, you need to remove the `${{` `}}` to make it work.

**Example with if condition:**

```
  job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      
      - name: step-1
        id: xyz
        run: echo "::set-output name=acc::$(echo $RANDOM)"
      
      - name: step-2
        if: steps.xyz.outputs.acc < 1
        run: |
          echo "Number lower than 1"
          echo "${{ steps.xyz.outputs.acc }}"
      
      - name: step-3
        if: steps.xyz.outputs.acc > 1
        run: |
          echo "Number higher than 1"
          echo "${{ steps.xyz.outputs.acc }}"
```

Comment: I am confused, can you tell me how to make the   if: ${{steps.get_acc.outputs.acc <1 }} works? in other words how to make  steps.get_acc.outputs.acc an integer?

Comment: No problem, I made an example here in `job5`: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/8-outputs-workflow.yml

Basically, you don't need the `${{` `}}` in the if condition. I will update the answer above with the correct syntax.

Comment: Removing the braces from the `if` condition isn't necessary. The [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#about-expressions) state that they're *optional*, not that they must be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have been given an answer on how to handle it as an integer, but given that you are setting the output via code. Why not just evaluate the integer in your code and then set a true/false boolean value or a Y/N string? If all you need to do is use the value as an If condition why bother to set the integer value? You could just evaluate it and set the condition at the source.